# Finding a function with given partial derivatives dx dy

Tags: integration, functions, derivatives

I need to find a function $f(x,y)$ such that

$f(x,y)dx = \frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+y}}$

and

$f(x,y)dy = \frac{1}{2}\frac{y}{\sqrt{x+y}}$

how can this be solved?

Comment: Do you rather mean those expressions you wrote are $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ & $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ ?

Comment: I imagine when you write $f\,dx$ you mean $\partial f/\partial x$. Are you sure you copied the problem correctly? (did it actually ask you to find such an $f$?)

Comment: Yes, apologies for the notation what I meant was $ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} $ and $ \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} $. It is actually a "practical problem I have" and basically need to find a function or if it doesnt exist its best approximation so that the derivatives equal those expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function $f$. If there were it would contradict the fact that $$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y }=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}.$$

Comment: Isn't that true only for for functions for which the second order mixed partial derivatives are *continuous* ?\

Comment: @Joanpemo Yes. And it's clear that the second-order mixed partial _are_ continuous... (hint: you can calculate a second-order partial by differentiating a first-order partial)

Comment: And if the function did exist how would I go about solving for it?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you.

Comment: @mtm Strictly speaking that's a meaningless question. Anyway: Find a book on elementary differential equations, and see the section on "exact equations".

Comment: Many thanks for all your replies this has been extremely useful.